# Hello, i'm developing chat app and require feature like WhatsApp for custom notification Tone. I am using FCM for Notification

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

After research on Google for 2 days, I came to know we have to add sound in a bundle and have to use that as custom tones. If this is the scenario then I would like to get the list of tones available in apple's `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds.`

Or if this is not required and we can just set name in JSON payload of notification and that works well then can anyone suggest JSON pattern or sound name format that should be used to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use APNS or FCM for Push Notification.i will prefer APNS

Comment: Thanks for showing interest but I am already using FCM. And i have some other issues please ready Question Again.

Comment: @ParthPatoliya when  i asnswer at time question was not clear